# Hausdorff measure of the Cartesian square of a Cantor like set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

Define

$K_{0}=[0,1] $

$K_{1}=[0,1/8]\cup[1-1/8,1] $

$K_{2}=[0,1/8^{2}]\cup[1/8-1/8^{2},1/8]\cup[7/8,7/8+1/8^{2}]\cup[1-1/8^{2},1] $

and so on... then put $K=\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty}K_i$

---

[Claim:
I can prove $0<H_{1/3}(K)<+\infty$ where H is the Hausdorff Measure.]

This is done by defining a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ $:[0,1]\to [0,1] $ as

$f_{0}(x)=x$

Then for n=1,2,...

$f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{2}f_{n-1}(8x)$ for $x\in [0,1/8]$

$f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{2} $ for $x\in [1/8,7/8]$

$f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}f_{n-1}(8x-7)$ for $x\in [7/8,1]$

Proving these are Cauchy looking at the limit and using some theorems and results to come to the claim.

My question is then how would I prove $0<H_{2/3}(K\times K)<+\infty$

Answer (score 0):

#### Upper bound on $H^{2/3}$

The set $K\times K$ is naturally covered by

- $1$ square with diameter $\sqrt{2}$; or
- $4$ squares with diameter $8^{-1}\sqrt{2}$; or
- $4^2$ squares with diameter $8^{-2}\sqrt{2}$; or  ...
- $4^k$ squares with diameter $8^{-k}\sqrt{2}$.

In each of these covers, the sum of $(\operatorname{diam} Q_j)^{2/3}$, where $Q_j$ are the squares, is the same, specifically $2^{1/3}$. And for any given $\delta>0$, there is $k$ such that $8^{-k}\sqrt{2}<\delta$. So, by the definition of $H^{2/3}$, we have $H^{2/3}(K\times K)  \le 2^{1/3}$.

#### Lower bound on $H^{2/3}$

Let $\mu$ be the restriction of the Hausdorff measure $H^{1/3}$ to the set $K$. You know that $\mu$ is positive and finite. Let $I$ be any interval of $k$th generation used in the construction of $K$; that is $|I| = 8^{-k}$. Since $K\cap I$ is just a scaled copy of $K$, scaled down by $8^{-k}$, it follows that $\mu(I) = 2^{-k} \mu(K)$. From this one can conclude that there is a constant $C$ such that 
$$
\mu(E) \le C(\operatorname{diam} E)^{1/3} \quad \forall E\subset K \tag1
$$
(Just cover $E$ by two suitable intervals like $I$ above.)

Consider the product measure $\nu = \mu\times \mu$, which is supported on  $K\times K$. From (1) it follows that 
$$
\nu(E) \le C(\operatorname{diam} E)^{2/3} \quad \forall E\subset K\times K \tag2
$$
Let $(E_j)$ be any cover of $K\times K$. Then
$$
\sum_j (\operatorname{diam} E_j)^{2/3} \ge C^{-1} \sum_j \nu(E_j) \ge C^{-1}\nu(K\times K)  
$$
Since this is true for any cover, $H^{2/3}(K\times K)\ge C^{-1}\nu(K\times K) > 0$.

---

Remark: both parts are quite typical for this kind of argument: an explicit cover to estimate Hausdorff measure from above; a positive measure with a growth bound (2) to estimate it from below (*mass distribution principle*). By combining the mass distribution principle with a deeper result, [Frostman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frostman_lemma), one concludes that 
$$
H^t(S) > 0 \text{ and } H^s(B) > 0 \implies H^{t+s}(A\times B)
$$
in general.

Comment: Im finding the  it hard to follow that $μ(I)=2^{−k}μ(K)$ feel like it should be $8^{-k}$